# How do I get the local Date time in js in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have an application that relies heavily on dates which runs smoothly on Chrome but not on FireFox because it changes my date objects because of the TimezoneOffset

In Chrome when I make a `new Date()` and `setHours(0,0,0)` I get `Thu Jul 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European summer time)` but when doing the same for FireFox I get `Date 2018-07-11T22:00:00.549Z` which is detrimental to my application..

is there a way to fix this? so that also in firefox it uses the date that I requested. because if it stays like this, it'll never reach the last day of the month because it'll stop at `30-month-year 22:00:00` instead of `31-month-year 00:00:00` and it'll be like the 31st never existed..

Also because of this, accourding to FireFox my employees now work from 06:30 (AM) till 15:00 (3PM) instead of 8:30 (AM) till 17:00 (5 PM).

**EDIT**

Right now I've come up with something that works but seems dirty to me..

```
var is_firefox = /firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0);
if(is_firefox){
    var timezoneOffset = Math.abs(today.getTimezoneOffset());
    timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset/60;
    today.add(timezoneOffset).hours();
}
```

this checks if the used browser is firefox, if so it gets the timezoneOffset, converts it to hours. and adds those hours to the date object using [dateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).. but this way I have to do this for every date object I have..

Answer (score 0):

If your application relies heavily on dates have you tried to use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/) ? It won't rely on Chrome/Firefox to calculate and display dates.

Otherwise I guess that you have consoled logged these raw Date instances to get this kind of display ? 
You can access [Date.toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) to get the same format in Mozilla and Chrome.

Last of all, if the display isn't the same maybe it's because of a different browser version on your computer ?
Also, browsers take your timezoneoffset from your computer, if you run these tests in different configurations you might obtain a different timezoneoffset (obvious I know but it's worth saying)

Comment: I had forgotten MomentJS to be very honest... oops haha, I'm sure it'll come in very handy

Comment: aaaaand momentJS does the same in firefox. i gave a date of `2018-07-02T08:30:00` and moment(date) returned `Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: Date 2018-07-02T06:30:00.000Z, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _d: Date 2018-07-02T06:30:00.000Z, _isValid: true }`

Comment: Date.getUTCDate() just returns the day's number in the month in UTC. so that'll only return something like `2` when using the date in the comment above... and both browsers are up to date.

Comment: Sorry I meant `.toUTCString()` ! What does happen with Moment when you console `moment(yourDate).format()` ?

Comment: the same.. But I think I figured it out... you see.. when I `console.log` a date with a 00:00:00 time. it takes 2 more hours away and it ends on the day before. but if I `console log date.getDate()` it's still the same day. so I can compare each part of the date object and everything will be okay